# Can balls in quasi-normed space form a base for some topology？

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

Define a ball in a quasi-normed vector space as $B(x,r)=\{y|||x-y||_{quasi-norm}<r\}$. Is the collection of all balls a base for some topology?
The quasi-norm of a vector space is just a map from the space to non-negative real line which satisfies the three properties:
$x=0$ iff $||x||=0$(non-degeneracy); $||cx||=|c|||x||$(for any real $c$); There exists some constant $C$ such that for any $x$ and $y$,$||x+y||\le C(||x||+||y||)$.

Comment: What is a quasi norm?  Perhaps it creates a pretopology.

Comment: https://books.google.fr/books?id=lXZ95EKwjYUC&lpg=PA445&ots=SxLL-zN_r9&dq=quasinorm%20topology&hl=fr&pg=PA445#v=onepage&q=quasinorm%20topology&f=false

Answer (score 0):

[this link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=-2LFp8aQ1_UC&pg=PA1102&lpg=PA1102&dq=quasi-norm&source=bl&ots=nJgomOZxTm&sig=vfLi8__x8Y_p4fkYSIYT4h6jc-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM4brp1KXWAhVEPVAKHWNNAucQ6AEIZTAK#v=onepage&q=quasi-norm&f=false) (Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, Volume 2, page 1102) says we replace a quasi norm on $X$ by an equivalent $p$-subadditive quasi-norm $\|.\|_1$ (for some $0 < p \le 1$) that obeys $\|x + y\|_1 \le (\|x\|_1^p + \|y\|_1^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. Then a metric topology on $X$ is introduced by the metric $d(x,y)  =\|x-y\|^p$